# Which algorithm i should choose from KNN and CNN for audio binary classifiaction?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, knn

I am doing thesis on baby cry detection, I build the model with `CNN` and `KNN`, the train accuracy of `CNN` is `99%` and Test accuracy is `98%` and for KNN, train accuracy  is `98%` and Test accuracy is `98%`.
Please suggest me which algorithms I should choose and why?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about your data set?

Comment: The data set consist of baby cry audio and non-baby cry audio as two classes. i should classify sounds of baby cry and non baby cry

Comment: How many training data for baby cry do you have? And how many non-baby cry? How about your Test data ?

Comment: i had 361 baby cry and 270 non-babycry. = total 631. i had given 441 for training and 190 for testing.

Comment: I think your data set is quite small and it is better to don't use `CNN`.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain the advantages KNN over CNN.

Comment: @pooyan is right, CNN are hungry for data. It won't be useful for your problem.

Comment: thank you and i got SVM 98% same as KNN,  now which i should choose.

Comment: Personally think that if it is possible then CNN will give a better result but in your case because of size of your data set, it is better to use `machine learning` algorithm like `KNN`. But according to the size of your data set and the test result of your `cnn` I think there is a problem in your data set and your test data is very similar to your train data.

Comment: i will check with that thank you

Comment: i had worked on another audio data to classify baby cry and non-baby cry. now i got svm linear kernel train accuracy of 97% and test accuarcy 91%, knn train accuracy 95% and test accuracy is 91%. my dataset consist of 108 baby cry and 90 non baby cry, i had given 60 files for testing. now which one i should chose and why?

Answer (score -2):

In KNN, output completely relies on nearest neighbours, which may or may not be good choice. Also it is sensitive to distance metrics. More you can find  [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwirron_kfTfAhVONrwKHbyxDxoQFjAKegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbib.dbvis.de%2FuploadedFiles%2F155.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1kHHL14vh6n0Opw95IVL4g). And great [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions) on its distance metrics can be helpful for you.

On the other hand, CNN extract the features from the input data. Which are very helpful for making analysis. And recent success in the CNN specially **wavenet** for the audio application, i will prefer to go with CNN.

Edit: Considering your data-size, CNN is not good option here.

Comment: Better to give feedback, if you dislike someone answer.

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer but probably your last paragraph caused the down votes.

Comment: I appreciate and Thanks for pointing, i will update my answer. Actually, it is good to know, where your are doing mistake, which can be corrected next time.